# Is eval function necessary here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet, eval

I wanna ask you, if it's reasonable to omit the eval () func in this code. Peculiarly how

```
  <script>
...
...

        function addGeoJson (geoJsonPath, iconPath = "leaflet-2/images/marker-icon.png", iconSize = [30,50], popUpContent, sideBarContent)
         
        {$.getJSON(geoJsonPath,function(data){
        
          var geoIcon = L.icon({
                        iconUrl: iconPath,
                        iconSize: iconSize
                        });
      
        L.geoJson(data,{
          pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
            var marker = L.marker(latlng,{icon: geoIcon, riseOnHover: true});
            
            marker.bindPopup(eval(popUpContent));
            
            marker.on('mouseover',function() {
              document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = eval(sideBarContent);
            });
            
            marker.on('mouseout', function(){
              document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = " ";
            });
            
            return marker;
          }
           
        }).addTo(map);
      });
      };

var layer1pop = "feature.properties.name + '<br/>' + feature.properties.info";
var layer1side = "feature.properties.price + '<br/>' + feature.properties.web";

addGeoJson("points.geojson", undefined, undefined, layer1pop, layer1side);

...
...
</script>
```

I want to reusing the addGeoJson func with multiple geoJSON files and for each one us different template of marker, popup, sidebar etc. Switching seems to me insufficient in case I don't know how many properties geoJSON could have and also if I need to change order of properties items in popup for example I can just edit the parametr of addGeoJson fund. An error occurs of corse if I tried to pass

```
var layer1pop = feature.properties.name + '<br/>' + feature.properties.info;
var layer1side = feature.properties.price + '<br/>' + feature.properties.web;
```

directly for impossibility to reach a local `feature` and in time of passing parameters it doesn't even exist.
I tried to replace it with `new Function` but also `feature` cannot be reached.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you pass `feature` directly to `addGeoJson()` and transform it inside?

Comment: You are basically asking us how to process data we can't see. `eval()` is not going to create the logic you need for the processing. Perhaps you have some sort of categories you can use to help build that logic?

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, of corse I can create templates inside the func and switching them according to some parametr. But isn't it better to have less code and smaller func and adjust it only by parametres?

Comment: @charlietfl ```eval()``` works fine for me in this case, but I thought that will be better to omit any use of ```eval()``` due to some security risks and a lot of people call for relinquish the ```eval()``` func... Is there than any possibilities to change these contents just by calling the ```addGeoJson``` and of course some of code. I could have tens of these geoJson sources and in each one could be different properties, so I don't want to copy the code so many time for that.

Comment: My guess is it will work the same without eval() then also. Without an actual example of the geoJSON object it works on it is hard to tell

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks you for helping. Unfortunately it doesn't work without eval(). But passing the func via reply below works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not change line `marker.bindPopup(eval(popUpContent));`
to `marker.bindPopup(feature.properties.name + '<br/>' + feature.properties.info);`

and apply same logic to the second function.
If there is something that prevent you from it, re-write for it to work.
eval is an evil code-smell

If the mapping keep changing (i.e. what part of `feature` you will use) try passing a function that knows what to extract

```
var layer1pop = function(feature){
 return feature.properties.name + '<br/>' + feature.properties.info;
}
```

and then `marker.bindPopup(eval(popUpContent));`
becomes `marker.bindPopup(popUpContent(feature));`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Passing function works fine :) I tried it before, but now I think about I forgot pass ```feature``` data to ```layer1pop``` func and passed just ```marker.bindPopup(popUpContent);``` ... And about the first question, I don't want to do it cause I'd have to make new function (or copy whole block of code) for every new geoJson file (or popup/sidebar content).